# Is it possible to use multi keyboards with multi keyboard layouts simultaneously?

Tags: dvorak

Considering to switch to dvorak layout, but this terminal is used by multi users as the same user account. It is unacceptable to ask all people to switch layout, plus it is hard to use dvorak layout with a keyboard qwerty-ly labeled.

But there are spare (USB,qwerty) keyboards, so if I plug another keyboard in and be able to use multi layouts on different psyical keyboard simultaneously (I will rearrange letters on keys), the problem get solved.

solution for either windows or linux is fine. anyway thanks all.

Comment: I think Daniel gave a good suggestion, but while we're on the subject, I use dvorak on linux and switch back and forth between dvorak and qwerty fairly easily on any machine I work on. It's not that hard to use dvorak on a qwerty keyboard: nowadays, using dvorak and qwerty in 4 different languages, I couldn't care less what's printed on the keys. I imagine anyone who touch-types feels the same way.

Comment: thanks, maybe i should try to adapt the qwerty-labeled keyboards..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know nothing about Windows, but on Linux:

In my xorg.conf, the [Xkb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_keyboard_extension) options are in the "InputDevice" section, and therefore tied to a particular keyboard.  So I think there should be no problem at all to connect two keyboards and have them use different layouts.

You'd just need some way to identify them.  If they're a different model number or connect via a different port (e.g., PS/2 vs USB), that might be easiest.  Worst case, you have 2 USB keyboards of identical model, then you might need to write a new udev rule so you can distinguish them in your xorg.conf.

Answer (score 1):

If you install both layouts, you can quickly switch between them using Alt+Shift. So you can plug in two keyboards, and switch the layouts when switching keyboards.