# Two keyboards - one qwerty one dvorak. Can windows use both simultaneously?

Tags: windows, keyboard-layout, dvorak, qwerty

Similar to this question: [Is it possible to use multi keyboards with multi keyboard layouts simultaneously?](https://superuser.com/questions/135623/is-it-possible-to-use-multi-keyboards-with-multi-keyboard-layouts-simultaneously) - I have two keyboards plugged in simultaneously. Both are querty keyboards, but I've rearranged the keys on one to be a dvorak layout.

I'd like to find some way to configure windows (XP) such that while both keyboards are plugged in, typing on each results in it's respective layout. I'd prefer if there was someway to have the system automatically use the desired layout based on which USB keyboard it is receiving input from.

If no such solution is possible, I would settle for a fast way of switching between US English and US English Dvorak languages so that in a pinch I can easily go from one to the other.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add both layouts in the keyboard list as shown below under "Installed Services". Then after applying settings, your left <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> will allow you to switch between the layouts. Or you could display the language toolbar in your taskbar to allow easy switching. (Right click taskbar > toolbars > Language...)

[image]

*Screenshot from [here](http://askville.amazon.com/SimilarQuestions.do?req=cyrillic-keyboard-email-friend-russia-windows-xp)*